# How gets QtreeView and TreeModel synchronized

Tags: python, pyqt, qtreeview, qmodelindex

I'm using pyqt5 and python 3.6.
I am confused about index functions in QModel/TreeView and ask here to clear my knot in brain. Some threads confused me more because they are very special. My question is more or less a basic one.

I have a model (based on [Uludag's great tutorials](http://www.yasinuludag.com/PyQt/Tutorial04/Tutorial04_TreeModel.py)) with data and did set it to my tree:

```
treeView = QTreeView()
treeView.show()
treeView.setModel(model)
#additional code
treeView.clicked.connect(treeViewStructure_clicked)
```

Now I have to prepare further action in the program based on the selected item. I can get the item by

```
def treeViewStructure_clicked(self):
    #get the row of the click and print
    index = treeView.currentIndex()
    print(index.row())
    print('selected item index at %s with data: %s' % (index.row(), index.data()))
```

So far so good. But the index is generated from treeView (model doesn't work). How can I connect the selection form the view to the model, so that I have the correct Modelindex and can change data in the model?
And of course, how to write them back that they will get synchronized? In other words, which index do I need for what and where and where do they come from?

Comment: The tree just delegates to whatever model is has. So the indexes always come from the model.

Comment: Thanks! That means e.g. if an item in the Tree is clicked, the index in the model is set. So I must have another problem..

Answer (score 0):

I would love to leave a comment but I don't have enough reputation.

Since your implementation of model did not include a method that could return the selected index, I have to get it from pyqt5. Since treeView is a QTreeView, you can:
`treeView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()`

the information is from [here](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#model). 
These will return a QModelIndex list, which has an [api](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmodelindex.html) here.
(note that although there are code examples on this website, it's in C++, but it should still be readable)

In the api, you can get the row and column as well as parent from the QModelIndex object.

Normally, I'd just modify the data via the object returned by treeView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes().

for example:

```
arr = treeView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
index = arr[0]
```

then just modify index.

but if you MUST use your own model for whatever reason, there is one thing you can do.
Since it extends QAbstractItemModel, you can use the index function. 
For example:

```
arr = treeView.selectionModel().selectedIndexes()
indexTemp = arr[0]
index = model.index(indexTemp.row(), indexTemp.column(), indexTemp.parent())
```

then modify the value through setData funtion

But as you can see, it's an extra step to get the same object